# What promotions does the Giant Death Robot get?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization V, what promotions does the Giant Death Robot get?

I know Drill, Shock and Sentry, but are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

Can't remember them all but I know they get in addition to what's already mentioned:

- Blitz (multiple attacks per turn)
- Mobility (+1 movement)
- Formation (+25% against mounted)
- Charge (+25% against wounded)
- Survivalism (+1 health every turn regardless of action performed;
  +50% defence)